# Disambiguation of "fluff" vs. chiefly AmEng "lint" vs. chiefly BrEng "bobbles" vs. "pills" for French "peluches"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, ambiguity, vernacular, disambiguities

Robert & Collins French and English Dictionary, Ed. 1985 gives:

> lint: (US: [*fluff*](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/fluff)) peluches *nfpl*
>
> [peluche](http://www.la-definition.fr/definition/peluche) (=*bouloche*): bit of fluff; fluff [Collins French-English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/peluche)

Now, these are the definitions of ***lint***, ***fluff***, ***bobbles***, and ***peluches*** sourced from WordReference English French - French English Dictionary:

> **lint:**
>
> (*fabric fibres*) (**on a garment** sur un vêtement)   peluches *nfpl* : *John picked some lint out of his pocket and threw it away*. [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/lint)
>
> **fluff:**
>
> (*dustball, lint*) (**esp. on a garment** sur un vêtement surtout) peluches *nfpl*
>
> (**on the floor** par terre)  mouton, mouton de poussière *nm*
>
> (**on the floor** par terre)  chaton *nm*
>
> *Karen swept some fluff out from under the sofa*.
>
> **ⓘ** *Le pull que j'ai acheté la semaine dernière commence déjà à faire des peluches* (The sweater that I bought last week is already [**pilling**](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/boulocher.190863/)) [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/fluff)
>
> **bobble**:
>
> *n.* *UK*, *informal* (*fabric*: pill) (*tissu*) peluche *nf*; (*familier*) bouloche *nf*
>
> bobble *vi* *UK*, *informal* (*fabric*: pill) (*tissu*) pelucher⇒ *vi*; boulocher⇒ *vi*; faire des peluches *loc v*
>
> *My brand new jumper (BrEng)/sweater is already bobbling (BrEng)/pilling after just one wash.*
>
> *Mon pull tout neuf est déjà en train de pelucher après un seul lavage.*
>
> **peluche**:
>
> *nf* (morceau de fibre d'un vêtement) bobble *n*
>
> *Après plusieurs passages à la machine, mon pull avait plein de peluches.*
>
> *After several washes, my jumper (BrEng)/sweater was covered in bobbles (BrEng)/pills.* [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/peluche)

And so, how do the terms ***lint*** (Chiefly AmEng), ***fluff***, and ***pills/bobbles (BrEng)*** for French [***peluches***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=peluches+sur+pull+en+laine&biw=513&bih=337&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF8KzokonKAhUBYg8KHfTYA5MQ_AUIBigB) differ from each other?

Comment: The only context in which I have heard *lint* used in Britain is its meaning 2 in the ODO - *a fabric, originally of linen, with a raised nap on one side, used for dressing wounds*. The first meaning, of which I was previously unaware is *short, fine fibres which separate from the surface of cloth or yarn during processing*. I would be surprised if American English is any different as regards such a basically occurring item.

Comment: @WS2 How about that meaning of "lint" for "dustball, which apparently is specific to AmEng? Did you have any knowledge of that AmEng usage?

Comment: The Cambridge Dictionary makes the following distinction: 
 1) mainly UK -  ​soft ​material made from ​cloth ​threads, used for ​protecting ​injuries
2) mainly US  - ​small ​loose ​pieces of ​cotton, ​wool, etc. that ​stick on the ​surface of a ​fabric, etc. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lint

Comment: @Elian: as far as I know, we do not use *lint* for *dustball*.

Comment: No I didn't. Nor does the OED. Tell me more! I am though discovering new things since you posed the question, like - for example - that it is the universal name for *flax* in Scotland. It is also the name that is often used scientifically, both for the plant and for the flax prepared for spinning.

Comment: @Elian: *peluche* seems to have two translations to English that you're confusing: (1) dustball. (2) lint. The difference is that *dustballs* collect on the floor under furniture, while *lint* is stuff that sticks to clothing.

Comment: @Elian Can you clean up/edit this in your first ~5 lines? It is unclear what is lint, fluff, flint. (please try to make it parallel).

Comment: @PeterShor Then, what's that AmEng meaning supported by CED, "staple fiber for making cotton yarn," which actually differs from what is meant iby French "peluches (=fuzz)"?

Comment: @Elian 'linty' is not a common term (certainly not linty sweater), unless you are speaking very informally and using the very new pattern of turning a noun or verb into an adjective by adding -y. 'fluffy' is a classic word though.

Comment: From [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lint): *lint (n.)
late 14c., "flax prepared for spinning," also "refuse of flax used as kindling," somehow from the source of Old English lin "flax" (see linen), perhaps from or by influence of Middle French linette "grain of flax," diminutive of lin "flax," from Latin linum "flax, linen."* So originally, *lint* meant linen fiber ready to be spun into cloth. The CED definition  seems to be cotton fiber ready to be spun. *American Heritage*: The mass of soft fibers surrounding the seeds of unginned cotton.

Comment: In AmE, 'lint' is very small, something you need to pick off a sweater (or your navel) with your thumb and index finger. 'fluff' is much more general, can be large dusty airy things can even be whipped food. A pillow that is fluffy (implied on the inside; a description of the entire object) is very comfortable; one that is linty (implied on the outside; a description of the surface) is not.

Comment: @PeterShor Actually, the French for "dustball" is "mouton," whereas "fluff/lint" is "peluche(s) or "bourre"...

Comment: ***Lint (material)***: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(material)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is much clearer to me now. The definition of lint as "staple fibre for making cotton yarn" is a technical meaning that most people (= me and I'm extrapolating) do not have anywhere near to the primary meaning. So I would not use that to compare anything.

Comment: It would seem to me dangerous to apply exactly the same word to something used as a medical dressing, as you would to a bit of fluff that gathered under the bed. I have never heard the word *lint* applied to any old random accumulation of fibres, such as the waste extraction from a hot-air clothes drier - only as wound dressing. Indeed it came as a surprise to learn that the Scots use it to mean *flax*.

Comment: @Mitch Since "lint/fluff" means "peluches", I can't seem to figure out why I cannot say in English, "I bought that sweater two weeks ago and it's already getting fluffy"?

Comment: @Mitch https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22fluffy+jumper%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjoptfy9IjKAhWG_w4KHZwbC5wQ_AUIBSgA#q=%22sweater+is+getting+fluffy%22

Comment: Probably because we'd say "I bought that sweater two weeks ago and it's already shedding" or "already pilling".

Comment: @WS2: Americans don't use *lint* to mean wound dressing. So the danger is only when there's a trans-Atlantic misunderstanding.

Comment: @Elian 'Aucun résultat trouvé pour "sweater is getting fluffy". but a fluffy sweater would work. Yes, I see 'linty sweater' in the links but it sounds really wrong to me (or very very new and informal) so I wouldn't use it as definitional.

Comment: @Mitch But isn't "fluff/lint" just about the same as "fuzz" on a sweater? If so, how come I can't say, "the sweater is getting fluffy"? https://www.google.fr/search?q=peluches+sur+pull+en+laine&biw=513&bih=337&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF8KzokonKAhUBYg8KHfTYA5MQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=bouloches+sur+pull+en+laine&imgrc=JwXssRKj-50jiM%3A

Comment: "lint on a sweater" best, "fuzz on a sweater" pretty good (actually just as common but 'lint' sounds more 'correct'), "fluff on a sweater" OK. "The sweater has/is getting/is collecting/ a lot of lint" best, "the sweater is getting fuzzy" almost as good. "The sweater is getting fluffy" means something different, it means that the sweater used to be thinner but from use maybe it is now 'fuller' or more puffed up, like a pillow.

Comment: *linty* is a very rarely used word, and *fluffy* means something else. As @Mitch says, *fuzzy* is fine.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, you live and learn! Until today the only context I'd ever heard *lint* said was as the stuff a nurse uses either to apply some ointment, or gel (such as before she sticks a needle in you), or as  is placed in contact with the wound before a bandage is applied - all highly sanitized. So what in America would you call the material with a raised nap which is used for that purpose? This is one of the *faux amis* of which the French speak - such as what we call bacon, they call lard.

Comment: @PeterShor I've also discovered as a result of this that you don't use the term *cotton wool* either. According to the ODO you call it *raw cotton* which is what I suppose it original was.

Comment: @WS2 "bacon" is also used in French... https://www.google.fr/search?biw=478&bih=315&noj=1&ei=0cmGVvq4KMqNaoLspfAN&q=%22bacon+et+des+oeufs%22&oq=%22bacon+et+des+oeufs%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i22i30l2.4159.17761.0.18165.36.35.0.1.1.0.433.7389.0j20j8j3j2.33.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..15.21.5037.3.iaybuGMKuqQ

Comment: @Elian Yes, but only as the adoption of an Anglicism to mean *smoked back bacon* (Hachette) (which is the kind mostly eaten in Britain). When I took my mock O Level French exam in 1960, we were given a piece of French to translate into English. It was describing someone cooking who put some *lard* into a pan with some eggs. We were later warned by the teacher to be on our guard against attempts such as this to catch us out. We needed to be aware of *faux-amis*. *Lard*, at least in those days translated as *bacon*. My guess is that *bacon* has arrived as a French word in the last 40 years.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not sure what you are talking about "the material with a raised nap which is used for that purpose". Can you give a link to a picture for that? Is it 'gauze' or 'cheese cloth'? (same stuff as gauze but not at all what AmE's call the medical stuff).

Comment: @Mitch [This is the stuff](http://www.physical-sports.co.uk/sports-first-aid-products/wound-care/swabs-padding/absorbent-lint-25g/?gclid=CjwKEAiA5Ji0BRC5huTCyOTR3wISJACH4Bx4XfWIkRCjMsuU-mUnKPo-jU5WMhiBp9G_ZINx0LaRVxoCiXnw_wcB). It looks as if you may call it *wound dressing*. [this is a better close-up look](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Fast-Aid-Absorbent-Lint-500g/181955517630?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3D39c2a5d6098341a4a40e1e5e02f7b1f5%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D11%26rkt%3D13%26sd%3D151627060023)

Comment: @WS2 that link only shows a picture of a box. It doesn't have a picture of the substance we are discussing.

Comment: @Mitch I did add a further picture to my earlier comment. It is difficult to find a close-up picture. Here is a [description from a medical dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/lint). it is interesting that some of the more significant differences I have discovered between the different versions of English we speak, since I have used this site, appear in the medical field.

Comment: @WS2: this is getting pretty far afield from the original question, but we wouldn't call something *raw cotton* unless it came directly from the cotton plants. We use *cotton balls* if the *cotton wool* comes in a round shape.

Comment: @WS2 re 'absorbent lint' - thanks for the picture. Unfortunately it is not close enough to tell the difference with 'surgical gauze'. The dictionary entries seem to be synonymous but don't explicitly connect the two. And it may be that 'absorbent lint' is used in medical circles in the US (it is not clear from any of the links).

Comment: @Mitch  [This leaflet] has *gauze swabs*, *cotton wool* and *lint* on offer. So they are all clearly different things. I'm still not clear from Peter's comment if you use the term *cotton wool*? It is the basis of metaphors, such as those directed at mothers (and possibly fathers) who try to *keep their kids wrapped in cotton wool, even when they are teenagers*.

Comment: @Mitch [This is the leaflet](http://firstmedical.co.uk/epages/2e774740-9e39-4ca9-987d-5f7888c83a7f.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/2e774740-9e39-4ca9-987d-5f7888c83a7f/Categories/121/6/14)

Comment: @WS2 In AmE we do not use 'cotton wool'. it's just cotton if it's from the cotton plant, and just wool if it comes from sheep. We don't have that saying at all, with cotton wool or anything else (I'm sure there's a saying for that but can't think of it).

Comment: @Mitch The obvious reason, I suppose, is that America is a land where cotton is grown and people know what it looks like in its raw state. But domestically, if you call the fluffy stuff by the same name as the material which your clothes are made of, it would seem confusing to me. Let's say you had a fragile object you were trying to pack, and someone said *wrap it in cotton*. How would you know whether they meant raw cotton (cotton-wool), or an old shirt?

Comment: @Mitch I just looked in the OED, and you will find this interesting. The word *cotton wool* has references as far back as 1589. And it is clear that the English called the raw stuff *cotton wool* from earliest times in its discovery: 
 *a. Cotton in its raw and woolly state, as gathered from the bolls of the plant; raw cotton.*
*1589   J. Chilton in R. Hakluyt Princ. Navigations iii. 591   In this Countrie there is great store of Cotton wooll, whereof the Indians make fine linnen cloth.*

The metaphorical senses, which I mentioned, are also included.

Comment: @WS2 Nice on the OED find. German says Baumwolle (literal correspondence). But at least the one colony missed that. To me 'cotton wool' makes me go cross-eyed, is it cotton or is it wool? I don't know! Re shirt, well, you'd just say that then, wrap it in some cotton _cloth_ or cotton balls or here take this, it's cotton!

Comment: @Mitch These were the other examples - just for interest's sake. 
*1653   H. Cogan tr. F. M. Pinto Voy. & Adventures lv. 215   They apparel themselves with Stuffs made of Silk and Cotten-wool.

1704   London Gaz. No. 3983/4   The Cargo..consisting of..Cotton-yarn, Cotton-wooll, &c.

1813   Vansittart in Examiner 5 Apr. 217/2   The Import of Cotton Wool from the United States.

1868   J. E. T. Rogers Man. Polit. Econ. (1876) ii. 11   In a country like India the same person grows, gathers, cleanses and spins the cotton-wool.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words

> *bobble* (mainly U.K.) and [*pill*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pill_(textile))

generally refer to clumps on an item of clothing that are formed by fibers from that item's fabric clumping together; *pills* and *bobbles* are generally attached to fabric they form on.

The word

> *[lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(material))* (mainly U.S.)

refers to fibers that are superficially stuck to the item, often with static electricity, but can easily be removed. This seems to be called [fluff](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fluff) in the U.K.

Comment: Shor Then, what is "fluff" in the US in terms of textile?

Comment: @Elian: I don't believe we use the word *fluff* very much in terms of textile in the U.S., but when we do, I think it would mean the same as in the U.K.

Answer (score 2):

The only terms familiar in the US are *lint*, *fluff*, and *pills*.

*Lint* is some sort of unwoven fibrous material that has accumulated on fabric or some similar surface.

*Fluff* is any sort of "fluffy" unwoven fibrous material, usually in a heavier accumulation than typical of *lint*.  (Light snow is often described as "fluff".)

*Pills* are [small ball-like bits of fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pill_%28textile%29) that have been created by friction against a lint-covered or loosely-woven surface.  (The occurrence of this on a piece of fabric is is known as "pilling.)

(There are also "dust bunnies" which are large balls of lint/fluff/dust that accumulate, eg, under beds and other areas where airflow encourages them.)

Comment: @Elian - If you search for "pilling of fabric" you will get a lot of hits.

Comment: Would saying "covered in fuzz balls" be more idiomatic? https://www.google.fr/search?biw=513&bih=337&noj=1&ei=XOSGVpvqM8XoPcahlZgG&q=%22covered+in+fuzz+balls%22&oq=%22covered+in+fuzz+balls%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...11458.15769.0.16168.8.8.0.0.0.0.317.1848.0j3j4j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..4.4.944.-n81ENdj_s4

Comment: @Elian - Depends on who you're talking to.  "Pilling" would be more idiomatic to an adult who must deal with laundry on a regular basis, "fuzz balls" would be more familiar to a teenager, eg.